# Replace NaN values with previous no-NaN value in a 1d Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1d Numpy array with NaNs and no NaNs values:

```
arr = np.array([4, np.nan, np.nan, 3, np.nan, 5])
```

I need to replace NaN values with previous no-NaN value and replace no-NaN values with NaN, as per below:

```
result = np.array([np.nan, 4, 4, np.nan, 3, 5])
```

Thanks in advance.

Tommaso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Pandas is available, you can use [`ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html), and then replace the original non-Nan values with a boolean mask:

```py
import pandas 
arr2 = pd.Series(arr).ffill()
mask = ~np.isnan(arr) # all elements which started non-NaN
mask[-1] = False # last element will never forward-fill
arr2[mask] = np.nan # replace non-NaNs with NaNs
```

Output:

```py
arr2
0    NaN
1    4.0
2    4.0
3    NaN
4    3.0
5    5.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

if not using pandas then:

```
arr = np.array([4.1, np.nan, np.nan, 3.1, np.nan, 5.1])
arr2 = np.array([])
val=0
for n in arr:
    if ~np.isnan(n):
        val = n
        arr2= np.append(arr2,np.nan)
    else:
        arr2= np.append(arr2,val)
```

output:
arr

array([4.1, nan, nan, 3.1, nan, 5.1])

arr2

array([nan, 4.1, 4.1, nan, 3.1, nan])